# When to specify model associated with collection/view in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This isn't very crucial but I was wondering what is considered best practice as I've seen it done both ways.

Binding model in view (or collection) declaration:

```
var FooView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model : fooModel
});
```

vs. binding model only at initialization:

```
App.views.foo = new FooView({ model : fooModel });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are associating all the future `FooView` instances to the same Model due you're making the association in a Class level. I've never seen this approach to be used.

The second case is the only one I use, and the only one I've seen out there. In this case you are associating a *concrete instance of a View* with a *concrete instance of a Model*.

#### Update

You can't compare the association between View and Model with the association between Collection and Model.

```
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : FooModel
});
```

Put attention I'm using `FooModel` (related to the Class) and not `fooModel` related to a concrete instance.

In a Collection is done in a Class level due this association is not with a concrete Model instance but with the Model class, so the Collection is able to instantiate instances of this concrete Model class, and also can access to class properties like `Model.urlRoot` and so on.

Comment: Here is an example of the first: http://wekeroad.com/2011/08/12/the-backbone-js-todo-list-refactored-part-2. In the definition of the `Tasks` collection, a model is specified directly. Is this okay?